# XSL Template match Syntax

Tags: xslt

I am learning XSLT templates. If there is a syntax like below, what does it mean?

```
<xsl:template match="xyz:abc/xyz:def"/>
```

Does it mean that XYZ is a root and ABC is child? in that case why we need to use "/" and again XYZ?

Can anyone clarify me? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

It means, the element `def` who is a child of element `abc` where both elements belong to the namespace prefixed with `xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's just two names: match="PPP/CCC", so it matches any element whose name is CCC provided that its parent element is named PPP.

Secondly, these names happen to be qualified names. They are in the form xyz:abc, meaning that the local name must be abc, and the namespace must be the namespace URI associated with the prefix xyz.